# Reporting document-wide Javascript errors

Tags: javascript

I need a way to log all Javascript errors that may happen in a document. Obviously, an Ajax call to the logging script is no problem, but the window.onerror event doesn't fire for errors inside functions or in some other cases where the browser or web developer toolbar would report an error.

I'd rather not use try/catch because there's a lot of code in many places and I'd like a document-wide solution that would report all Javascript errors.

Is this even possible? I see so many high profile sites with Javascript errors, so obviously many developers either don't care or don't know about the errors.

Comment: Can you do this browser by browser? for example the console object in chrome might give you a list?

Comment: What do you mean browser by browser? How would I access the errors in the console object on Chrome?

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.exception.28error-object.5B.2C_object.2C_....5D.29 - doesn't seem to do what you want though.  Not sure its possible

Answer (score 1):

First, sorry if I misunderstood your question and your qualifications.

Seems to be you are not familliar with DeveloperTools, and you better should be : ) For example, in Chrome you can open DeveloperTools by pressing F12 or Ctrl+Shift+J. All your previous and upcoming JavaScript errors will be displayed in the Console tab as they occur.

Comment: Yup, you misunderstood. :) I want the page to report Javascript errors that may occur to the visitors of the site - then the page catches the error, sends it via Ajax to a script and the script sends me an e-mail telling me "A visitor just had a Javascript error 'someerror' on page 'someurl' on line #someline" along with their user agent. I did actually make all that, and it works on some Javascript errors, but not on most (those inside functions for example) because window.onerror doesn't catch those errors.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to do **some** automatic try-catch insertion, in a way where you do not need to alter your code. It's not easy.

You could try my project Muscula, that [logs JavaScript errors](http://muscula.com) with try-catch insertion and falls back on onerror when it's not possible.